# Getting React Developer Tools working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm attempting to use Facebook's [React Developer Tools](https://fb.me/react-devtools) in Chrome 40 under OS X 10.10.3. The extension installs correctly, but the React web inspector tab is blank. Having Googled around for this issue, I've also taken some additional steps:

- Made the `window.React` global available from my React web app. Now, as expected, when I enter `React` into the console, I see the React 0.13.3 object, not `undefined`.
- Opened Chrome's Extensions settings and made sure **Enabled** and **Allow Access to File URLs** are both checked.
- Relaunched Chrome for good measure, after doing the above.

Those options seem to have worked for some developers, but I am not among them. Am I missing some other step, or is the extension broken until Facebook updates it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is no longer relevant; The React DevTools team has since released a major new version that completely fixes this issue.